# onchange insert value into hidden input jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i select some data from my option i need the value to be showed when "onchange" the select... can someone help me ?

```
<select name="search_school" id="search_school" onchange="$('#search_school').val() = $('#school_name').val()">
```

I want the selected option value to be showed in the hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" name="school_name" id="school_name" value="" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want this as your onchange event:

```
<select name="search_school" id="search_school" onchange="$('#school_name').val($('#search_school').val())">
```

When you call `val()` without a parameter, it *fetches* the value of the element.  If you call it *with* a parameter like `val('some value');`, it sets the value of the element.

Comment: woow! Thanks ALOOT! I appreciate very much !

Comment: Wow.  Even though I gave a right answer that's extremely simple, you guys are downvoting it because it's got a difference in semantical set up?  That's pretty classy.  I could have gone into a whole spiel about why you might want to use `ready()` and the best way to organize your javascript, but the poster obviously just needed some direction with the `val()` function.  Sometimes keeping it simple is the best course of action.  Generally you should reserve a downvote for an incorrect answer.  Leave comments if you think it can be improved, or upvote other answers that are correct.

Comment: If you updated the answer to include the advice, and reasons to avoid it, Ill be back to remove the downvote.

Answer (score 6):

If you can, avoid inline event definition on html:

```
<select name="search_school" id="search_school">
...
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="school_name" id="school_name" />
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#search_school').change(function () {
        $('#school_name').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this, I think:

```
$("#search_school").change(function(){
  $(this).val($("#search_school option:selected").text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the selected value to your hidden control you should :

```
<select name="search_school" id="search_school"  onchange="$('#school_name').val($('#search_school').val())">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#search_school").change(
            function () {
                $('#school_name').attr('value', $("#search_school").val());
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```